# A Python function in Blender 3.0 seems to be forcing Blender to crash

Tags: python, scripting, blender

After updating to Blender 3.0, one of my functions seems to be straight up closing Blender on an instant.

Whole function:

```
# Loops through each collection and disables every object from viewport and render.
def disableAllObjs():
    for collection in bpy.data.collections:
        if collection.name != "Collection":
            for obj in collection.all_objects:
                obj.hide_viewport = True
                obj.hide_render = True
```

I did some debugging and it's specifically this part where it breaks:

```
obj.hide_viewport = True
obj.hide_render = True
```

I'm not sure if disabling everything so quickly seems to overload Blender, but this worked fluently in 2.93. Using that code outside of the loop works fine on a singular object, but breaks in the loop. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. It is a bug and worth reporting but since you want to hide all objects in the collections, you can use the collection's hide attributes.

Like below:

```
def disableAllObjs():
for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    if collection.name != "Collection":
        collection.hide_viewport = True
        collection.hide_render = True
```

Comment: I want to disable all to then enable a single object inside that collection, so this doesn't really work. I've uploaded this bug to the Blender forum and it's a known one with workarounds. Thanks for the help, though.